# View inside a view using CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Is it possible to display a view inside another view?

I have the following code:

```
<?php if ($result->type === 'brochure') : ?>
    <div>
        // massive template block
    </div>
<?php elseif ($result->type === 'library') : ?>
    <div>
        // massive template block different from above
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div>
        // massive template block different from both above
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to replace those with a content block so to speak. I had a look at [view blocks](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks) but I'm either using it wrong or it doesn't do what I want it to do.

Is this possible in CakePHP 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use elements for that.

first you should create elements in src/Template/Element directory with .ctp format like this

```
// in brochure.ctp file in  src/Template/Element
 <div>
    // your massive template block
</div>
```

then you can call elements like this :

```
<?php if ($result->type === 'brochure') : ?>

      <?= $this->element("brochure") ?>

<?php elseif ($result->type === 'library') : ?>

      <?= $this->element("library") ?>

<?php else : ?>

      <?= $this->element("default") ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It should be "**T**emplate" and "**E**lement", the lowercase names won't work with case sensitive filesystems.